# Is there a general way to motivate myself to study?

Tags: work, reading

I am a student of electrical and mechanical engineering. Ever since I joined, my hours of studying have been reduced significantly. That's not to say there is less study to be done though.

I usually find references of people being unmotivated to study via online posts, memes and discussion. I myself am, as well, unmotivated to study, with study meaning read the theory of a lesson or subject in a book or on the internet.

I find the act tedious although necessary. I do like the field i have selected but I consider reading to be a grindy part in the learning procedure overall. Exercises and practical examples seem less boring to me. Now at the university there is more theory involved thus the change in time devoted to studying. 
With that in mind i have tried various ways of motivating myself such as:

1. Enforcing it. So far the most effective method. Used ocassionally
   when deadlines are due. Downside is I get socially detached and also
   lack enthusiasm for my work.
2. Combining it with means of entertainment. Involves taking multiple
   few-minute breaks and/or performing a secondary activity whilst
   reading (listening to music, a video etc).
   You can imagine how this
   method can be distracting and unproductive.
3. Sloppy work. Learning only the essentials, skipping segments of a
   text. This way I am left with questions and gaps.
4. Interpersonal learning (Least favorite way). The system of learning that
   teachers usually propose. Not only do I deem them incompetent to
   deliver but also insufficient due to the fact they can't dedicate
   much time to an individual.

From your experience and knowledge, is there a lifehack that would help me study?

Answer (score 0):

For me Pomodoro Technique (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomodoro_Technique) works best.

You simply focus 25 minutes to the problem. No emails, not calls, no Facebook.

Then you take a break (Pomodoro suggests 5 minutes, I'm usually taking 10 minutes or so).

Then you focus again.

I found nice app on the internet https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hubalek.android.apps.focustimer that logs how many pomodoros I took per day.

Collecting more and more pomodoros motivates me to survive boring time.

Answer (score -1):

You can get motivation from your surrounding only. You just need to see that.

- If you think you need motivation then go and watch your mother. Remember all her sacrifices and struggles she has to make to watch you here today. Study so that you can give her all the happiest moments in her second innings of her life i.e. old age.
- If you think you need motivation then go and watch your father. Oh! Is he still not at home Oh! He will be working late today also. See your father's hard-work? Is he giving any excuse that from now he will not go to work. NO. Then study. Study to give your father peace in his also second innings.
- If you think you need motivation then go and watch your little sibling. You are thinking that she is not becoming mature. How will she take of our parents if she can't take care of herself? Study so that you can give your sibling that peace where she/he can say that my elder one who is now stable in life is there by my side.
- If you think you need motivation then go out and see our society. So you didn't like our society? So you have to give bribery to some officer to complete your work? You didn't like it? Then go and study for the betterment of the future of your nation.
- Oh!! So in fulfilling other's wish you forgot that your wishes were also there. So when will you fulfill yours? After death? NO. Then go and study. Study for yourself. Study for your life partner so that you both can enjoy life too.

If this is enough motivation for you then GO AND STUDY.